# Is it possible to overlay a three.js 3D render on top of another?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I took two 3D scenes rendered using three.js and put them in containers called scene1 and scene2. I can see any one of them on my webpage at a time, but when I try to render them simultaneously I see a black screen.

I took a [cloud animation](https://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/webgl/clouds/) (check here for [source code](https://github.com/WindowsVistaisCool/clouds/tree/main)) and put its code in a new file called clouds.js. Then I created another file called plane.js, and wrote code to render a 3D model of a cockpit. In index.html, the cloud animation goes in the scene1 div, and the cockpit model goes in the scene2 div. The idea was that when scene2 is overlayed on scene1, it will look like the user is sitting inside the cockpit of a moving plane.

Here's the contents of plane.js:

```
var renderCalls = [];
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderCalls.forEach((callback) => {
    callback();
  });
}
render();

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  80,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  800
);
camera.position.set(-1, -0.3, 0);
camera.rotation.x = (2 * Math.PI) / 180;

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffcc, 20, 200);
light.position.set(4, 30, -20);
scene.add(light);

var light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x20202a, 20, 100);
light2.position.set(30, -10, 30);
scene.add(light2);

var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = true;
loader.load("./assets/cockpit.glb", function (data) {
  var object = data.scene;
  object.position.set(0, 0, 0);

  scene.add(object);
});

var model_renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
model_renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
model_renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
model_renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
model_renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

window.addEventListener(
  "resize",
  function () {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    model_renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  },
  false
);
var container = document.getElementById("scene2");
container.appendChild(model_renderer.domElement);

function renderScene() {
  model_renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
renderCalls.push(renderScene);
```

Here's how the divs are arranged in index.html:

```
<div id="scene1"></div>
<div id="scene2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/clouds.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plane.js"></script>
```

When I comment out the third line, I can see the plane cockpit, and when I comment out the fourth line, I can see the clouds animation. But when both of them are present, it only shows a black screen.

The problem is that the cloud animation was created in 2011 and some of the components have since been deprecated in latest versions of three.js, and plane.js needs a later version of three.js. So any other way of achieving this simulation (other than overlaying) would involve me updating the clouds.js source code, which is beyond the scope of my knowledge at this time.